# Gradient Operator on Tensor Products of Two Vectors - Using Abstract Index Notation

Tags: differential-geometry

$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot(\vec{A}\vec{B})=\nabla_a(A^aB^b) \tag{1}$$

I'm trying to write left side of equations $(1)$ using abstract index notations. I'm sure $\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B} = A^{a}B_{a}$, which the contraction of index $a$ would give scalar. But when I'm a little bit confused when trying to put gradient in front of them. Should it be $\nabla_{b}(A^aB_{a})$ or should it be $\nabla_a(A^aB^b)$? I see the textbook (Introduction to differential geometry and general relativity, by Canbin Liang) is using latter but seems there is no reason to special treat the index of $A$?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116235/discussion-on-question-by-ning-cheng-gradient-operator-on-tensor-products-of-two).

Comment: That operation on the left of (1) is called the divergence, not the gradient.

Comment: @G.Smith is it true that gradient the very special case that acts on a scalar field? Otherwise it would be called divergence? I know if the operator acts on a vector in dot product fashion it is divergence. But here the operates is bivector?

Comment: The gradient of this bivector would be the three-index tensor $\vec{\nabla}(\vec{A}\vec{B})$ or $\nabla_c(A^aB^b)$ where there is no contraction. This generalizes to the gradient of a tensor with any number of indices; it just creates a higher-rank tensor with an additional index. When the index of the del operator is contracted with one of the indices of the tensor it is operating on, that’s called the divergence. This reduces the rank of the tensor operated on, by 1.

Comment: @G.Smith That makes sense and intuitive. Do you mind commenting a bit on the abstract of gradient, divergence and curl potentially? Is non-contraction for gradient and contraction for divergence general using differential geometry terms?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand what you are asking. My point of view is that you don’t *have* to think about these things in terms of differential geometry. These concepts apply even in simple flat Cartesian space.

Answer (score 1):

Dot products usually refer to the contraction between two indexes that close to the dot. In this case, dot close to the index of gradient $\vec\nabla$ and vector $\vec A$. We thus can reach the result: $$(\vec\nabla\cdot(\vec A\vec B))_b=\nabla_a(A^aB^b)$$
Note that the bracket $\vec\nabla\cdot\color{red}(\vec A\vec B\color{red})$ is emphasising that this divergence operation is not only acting on $\vec A$, but acting on the whole thing in the bracket $\vec A\otimes\vec B$, a bivector(or a tensor of type $(2,0)$)

If the non-index notion want to show the expression $\nabla_a(A^bB_b)$, then according to the discussion above, it will be looks like $\vec\nabla(\vec A\cdot\vec B)$.

You can find this divergence operator $\vec\nabla\cdot$ in a lot of places, like the conservation property of the stress-energy tensor $T_{ab}$: $\nabla^aT_{ab}=0$. It could be abstracted as a local linear map: $\vec\nabla\cdot(~\cdot~):\mathscr T_M(k,l)\to\mathscr T_M(k,l-1) $ or $\vec\nabla\cdot(~\cdot~):\mathscr T_M(k,l)\to\mathscr T_M(k-1,l) $
Hopefully, this can solve your confusion.

Answer (score -1):

$$\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B}=A_{\alpha}B^{\alpha}=C$$
where $C$ is  scalar.

the gradient of this dot product

$$\vec{\nabla}(\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B})=\vec{\nabla}(C)=(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}C,\frac{\partial}{\partial y}C,\frac{\partial}{\partial z}C)$$
about the notation we write

$$[\vec{\nabla}(\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B})]_{\alpha}=\partial_\alpha A_\beta B^\beta=\partial_\alpha C$$
Finnaly the expression you write in your question is

$$[(\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{A})\vec{B}]_{\alpha}=\partial_\beta A^\beta B_\alpha$$
so it is very simple you just take the divergence of $A$ then you multiply this scalar with $B$. There is no mystery or subtlety here.

Answer (score -2):

The dot product of two vectors is a scalar.
$$A^{\alpha}B_{\alpha} = \vec A \cdot \vec B$$

If $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ are defined over a region of space-time, you may be able to take derivatives of the product with respect to distance and time. Let us define a function $f = \vec A \cdot \vec B$. The gradient of $f$ is

$$\nabla f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \hat i + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}  \hat j + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \hat k+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \hat t$$
or in other notation
$$\nabla_{\alpha} f =  f_{,\alpha}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{\alpha}}$$

So your first formula should be

$$\nabla (\vec A \cdot \vec B) = \nabla_{\alpha} (A^{\beta} B_{\beta}) $$

---

Note that $\vec \nabla \cdot \vec A$ (or $\nabla \cdot \vec A$) is the divergence of a vector.

$$\nabla \cdot \vec A = \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \hat i + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}  \hat j + \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \hat k+ \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \hat t \right) \cdot \left( A_x \hat i + A_y \hat j + A_z \hat k + A_t \hat t\right)$$

$$= \frac{\partial A_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial A_y}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial A_z}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial A_t}{\partial t}$$